# Как скролить слайдер на элемент c текстом введённым в поиск?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, ui

Есть слайдер с картинками товаров и текстом к ним. Нужно что бы когда пользователь нажимает ctrl+F и вбивает что нибудь в поиск, то слайдер автоматически скролился бы на слайд с этим текстом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

*Подразумевается использовать стандарный браузернвй поиск*

*Кросбраузерность не очень важна, главное что фича нормально работала бы в хроме и в сафари*

*В качестве слайдера я использую swiper, но мне хотя бы для какого нибудь сладера понять как это можно сделать, а потом уж и к swiper придумаю как прикрутить*

Comment: А когда пользователь наживает `Ctrl+F`, какой поиск используется? Стандартный браузерский или кастомный на вашей странице?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, да стандартное

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , да стандартный, хотелось бы обойтись стандартным. Если свой то тогда всё понятно, за искючением того, как реализовать свой поиск, что бы он как стандарнтный выглядел.

Comment: Раз стандартный тогда я хз как. Боюсь, что даже никак. Более того, мне кажется стандартный поиск не сможет найти текст на ваших слайдах, если те слайды скрыты.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko . Сделать точно можно, так сделано на Беру.ру, только я не пойму как они это сделали. Поиск находит текст в слайде т.к.  все слайды есть в dom дереве, и просто не помещается в контейнер и потому не видны. Ещё сейчас эксперементировал с вёрсткой, оказывается что если поставить overflow:scroll вместо overflow:hidden, то браузер начинает скролить при поиске, но тут возникает проблема с тем, что появляется полоса прокрутки, которая не нужна.

Comment: Нужен код для воспроизведения проблемы.  Без примера кода вам мало кто сможет помочь.

Comment: Добавьте [mcve] в ваш вопрос

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно на js перехватывать нажатие этих клавиш и ставить callback в котором уже дальше отслеживать введенный текст и управлять в соотвествии слайдером.